# include windowsazuremessaging framework swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, azure-notificationhub

I copied the `WindowsAzureMessaging` framework into my Swift project. I keep getting error messages from Xcode saying it can't find the header file (in my bridging header) nor the module (`import WindowsAzureMessaging`).  How can I add this framework to my project?

Comment: Solved my own issue by adding the framework search path

Comment: could you please elaborate some more so other people could benefit? besides you can mark your own answer here as the correct...

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.1 , Xcode 7.1**:

1- Add WindowsAzureMessaging.framework to your bundle.

2- Add the following line in your bridging header file:

```
#import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h"
```

Now you have access to all the headers, use them like Swift classes in your project.